# Adjusting the buttons from top to the bottom in GUI Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

the code below is a GUI for converting a hexadecimal value to decimal and binary. The problem is that the buttons get printed on top, I have also attached some picture for reference as to how I want the result to be.

```
class MyFrames implements ActionListener
{

    JFrame DancingFinchFrame;

    static JLabel NewLabel, DecimalValue, BinaryValue, FinchSpeed;
    static JTextField textField, DecimalText, BinaryText, SpeedText;
    static JButton Convert, Dance;
    static String Hexadecimal, Binary;
    static int Decimal, Speed;


    MyFrames()  

    { 
        // creates a frame
        DancingFinchFrame=new JFrame("Calculator");
        DancingFinchFrame.setTitle("Dancing Finch");
        DancingFinchFrame.setSize(320, 280);
        DancingFinchFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        DancingFinchFrame.setResizable(false);
        DancingFinchFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        NewLabel = new JLabel("Please enter a hexadecimal value");
        NewLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        NewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        NewLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField.setColumns(20);

        Convert = new JButton("CONVERT");       
        Convert.setBounds(10, 400, 100, 40);
        
        
        DecimalValue = new JLabel("Decimal Value is ");
        DecimalValue.setVisible(false);
        DecimalValue.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
        DecimalValue.setVisible(false);

        DecimalText = new JTextField();
        DecimalText.setEditable(false);
        DecimalText.setVisible(false);
        DecimalValue.setLabelFor(DecimalText);
        DecimalText.setColumns(10);

        BinaryValue = new JLabel("Binary Value is ");
        BinaryValue.setVisible(false);
        BinaryValue.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
        BinaryValue.setToolTipText("");

        BinaryText = new JTextField();
        BinaryText.setEditable(false);
        BinaryText.setVisible(false);
        BinaryValue.setLabelFor(BinaryText);
        BinaryText.setColumns(10);

        FinchSpeed = new JLabel("Finch Speed is ");
        FinchSpeed.setVisible(false);
        FinchSpeed.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
        
        SpeedText = new JTextField();
        SpeedText.setVisible(false);
        SpeedText.setEditable(false);
        FinchSpeed.setLabelFor(SpeedText);
        SpeedText.setColumns(10);
        
        Dance = new JButton("DANCE");
        Dance.setVisible(false);**
        
    
        // creates the panel 
        JPanel mypanel = new JPanel();

        //adds action listeners and initialises the event handling for the buttons
        Convert.addActionListener(this); 
        Dance.addActionListener(this); 
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        // adds elements to the panel 
        mypanel.add(Convert); 
        mypanel.add(Dance); 
        mypanel.add(NewLabel); 
        mypanel.add(textField); 
        mypanel.add(DecimalValue); 
        mypanel.add(DecimalText); 
        mypanel.add(BinaryValue); 
        mypanel.add(BinaryText); 
        mypanel.add(FinchSpeed); 
        mypanel.add(SpeedText); 

        mypanel.setBackground(Color.white); 

        // adds panel to frame 
        DancingFinchFrame.add(mypanel); 
        DancingFinchFrame.setSize(320, 280); 
        DancingFinchFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        Hexadecimal = textField.getText();
        Decimal = DecimalConverter.HexaToDecimal(Hexadecimal);
        Binary = BinaryConverter.HexaToBinary(Hexadecimal);
        Speed = SpeedCalculator.Speed(Decimal);


        if(e.getSource()==Convert)

        {
            if (Decimal >= 144 && Decimal <= 255)

            {
                DecimalValue.setVisible(true);
                DecimalText.setVisible(true);
                BinaryValue.setVisible(true);
                BinaryText.setVisible(true);
                Dance.setVisible(true);
                FinchSpeed.setVisible(true);
                SpeedText.setVisible(true);
                DecimalText.setText(""+ Decimal);
                BinaryText.setText(""+ Binary);
                SpeedText.setText("" + Speed);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid input!", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                catch (Exception ne) 
                {
                    ne.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        else if (e.getSource()==Dance)  

        {
            int decimal = Integer.parseInt(SpeedText.getText());
            String binary = BinaryText.getText();

            FinchCommands Command = new FinchCommands();
            Command.Dance(decimal, binary);
        }
    }

    public JFrame getDancingFinchFrame() 

    {
        return DancingFinchFrame;
    }


}
```

The problem is that convert/ dance button gets printed at the top

[image: Buttons get printed on top]

This is what i wanna get

[image: the result that i want]

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you declare variables with a first uppercase letter, which is not standard and could be hard to handle when your program will grow or after some years to do others things.

Secondly, you do not use any Layout. You use a FlowLayout because it seems to be the default. But with a simple BorderLayout, you will be able to define areas for your controls and your fields.

To look deeper and learn how to use them, I provide you a good link :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html !

Answer (score 1):

This layout:

[image]

Can be produced using this code:

```
JPanel ui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,40,10,40));

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = 2;
gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

ui.add(new JLabel("Please enter a hexadecimal value"), gbc);
gbc.gridy = 1;
ui.add(new JTextField("90", 10), gbc);
gbc.gridy = 2;
ui.add(new JButton("Convert"), gbc);
gbc.gridy = 6;
ui.add(new JButton("Dance"), gbc);

gbc.gridwidth = 1;
String[] name = {"Decimal Value", "Binary Value", "Finch Speed"};
for (int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) {
    gbc.gridy = ii+3;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    ui.add(new JLabel(name[ii]), gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    ui.add(new JTextField(6), gbc);
}
```